# cakephp rename acl table name

Tags: cakephp, acl, authentication

I am new to cakephp and trying to follow the ACL Authentication tutorial from the cakephp book. However I would like to call my users table 'members' instead. so I have usernames and passwords stored in a table called 'members'. but the ACL auth always seems to be looking for a user model and users table. although that is not configured anywhere.

how can I tell the ACL/Auth component to look for the members table/model instead ?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

sorry I am stupid and it's late, I found the answer already.
the solution is to use $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member'; in the auth setup (function beforeFilter)